# Rails: How can I show a block with or without a link based on a condition (link_to_if)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have a complex block of tags (`<h3>`, `<p>`, ...) that I want to render with a link or without a link around it based on a condition.

I know about `link_to_if` that works like that:

```
<% link_to_if condition, name, path %>
```

if the condition is `false` only the name will be rendered.

And I know about the `link_to` with `&block`:

```
<% link_to path do %>
  [complex content]
<% end %>
```

I want a combination of both. A `link_to_if` statement that accepts a `&block`, so that the block will be rendered without a link around it, if the condition is `false`. Unfortunately the `link_to_if` statement with a `&block` works not like the `link_to` statement :(

Does anyone have suggestion for me? Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I wrote my own helper for this:

```
   def link_to_if_with_block condition, options, html_options={}, &block
     if condition
       link_to options, html_options, &block
     else
       capture &block
     end
   end
```

You can use it like this:

```
<%= link_to_if_with_block true, new_model_path { "test" } %>
<%= link_to_if_with_block true, new_model_path do %>
  Something more complicated
<% end %>
```

Comment: I just do not know how it works out with passing on all the different arguments to `link_to`, but I guess when you need something more sophisticated you will figure it out ;)

Comment: Hmmm. Something is odd with your helper method. If I use the Helper with `<%= %>` the block will be rendered once (with a link around it) if condition is true, but twice (wihtout a link) if the condition is false :(

Comment: `capture(&block)` instead of `block.call` does the job :)

Answer (score 4):

I just overwrote the built in method cause the block use they offer really doesn't make much sense for our use. Just add it to a helper and this will make link_to_if work just like link_to.

```
def link_to_if(*args,&block)
  args.insert 1, capture(&block) if block_given?

  super *args
end
```