# Conditional link_to block in Rails if condition is met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I would like to wrap a conditional link_to around some code that only renders the link if the following condition is met: IF `current_user.type == 'Agent'`. The content within the condition still needs to be rendered regardless.

My current block looks like this:

```
<% @jobs_published.in_groups_of(3, false) do |job| %>
    <div class="row">
        <%= link_to "/job/#{job.id}" do %>
            <div class="panel">
                <h4>Job</h4>
                <p><%= job.suburb %></p>
                <p><%= job.street_name %></p>
                <p><%= job.post_cide %></p>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:

### View:

```
<% @jobs_published.in_groups_of(3, false) do |job| %>
    <div class="row">
        <%= link_to_if current_user && current_user.type == 'Agent', { controller: "agents", action: "job", :id => job.id } do %>
            <div class="panel">
                <h4>Job</h4>
                <p><%= job.suburb %></p>
                <p><%= job.street_name %></p>
                <p><%= job.post_cide %></p>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

### ApplicationHelper:

```
def link_to_if(*args,&block)
    args.insert 1, capture(&block) if block_given?

    super *args
end
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25916594/2811283

Answer (score 0):

You should use `link_to_if`.

Here is the documentation link. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if

Comment: Thanks mate. See my comments above this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor, So you want to render the content inside but not as link, instead it should be simple span along with the contents.

Comment: Thanks but link_to_if yes I want to render everything inside my block I just want to wrap it all in a conditional href.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one

```
<% @jobs_published.in_groups_of(3, false) do |job| %>
    <div class="row">
        <%= link_to_if(current_user.type == 'Agent', "/job/#{job.id}") do %>
            <div class="panel">
                <h4>Job</h4>
                <p><%= job.suburb %></p>
                <p><%= job.street_name %></p>
                <p><%= job.post_cide %></p>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

There are many conditional link_to element

[link_to_if](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_if) ,  [link_to_unless](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless),  [link_to_unless_current](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to_unless_current)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @rajarshi-das. I've tried the above solution however it doesn't output anything within the block. The above solution renders like this: `<a href="/">/job/33</a>` so I tried: `<%= link_to_if current_user.type == 'Agent', "", "/job/#{job.id}" do %>` and the href is now correct however nothing inside the block is displaying still!

Comment: you have to use like this `<%= link_to_if current_user.type == 'Agent', "/job/#{job.id}", "/job/#{job.id}" do %>`

Comment: Thanks but it still isn't rendering anything inside my block e.g. 

`<div class="panel">
                <h4>Job</h4>
                <p><%= job.suburb %></p>
                <p><%= job.street_name %></p>
                <p><%= job.post_cide %></p>
            </div>`

Comment: I also don't need it rendering any string it only requires a href

Comment: is your current user type is 'Agent' see/debug what it is giving `<%= current_user.type %>`

Comment: Yep my current user type is agent